# Detect early tie in Connect 4

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm to detect an **early** tie in a Connect 4 game. As of now, I already check if the board is full and no wins have been detected but I would like to know as soon as the game can be deduced a tie.

For example, consider this game, where player `B` just played at position Row-5, Column-0:

```
    |
    v
5 | B |   |   |   |   |   |   |
4 | A | B | A | B | A | B | A |
3 | A | B | A | B | A | B | A |
2 | B | A | B | A | B | A | B |
1 | B | A | B | A | B | A | B |
0 | A | B | A | B | A | B | A |
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Then, the game is *not* considered a tie, because there is still a way for player `B` to win. Though if player `A` plays at Row-5, Column-1:

```
        |
        v
5 | B | A |   |   |   |   |   |
4 | A | B | A | B | A | B | A |
3 | A | B | A | B | A | B | A |
2 | B | A | B | A | B | A | B |
1 | B | A | B | A | B | A | B |
0 | A | B | A | B | A | B | A |
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

At this point, either player has no way to win: it going to be a tie. I would like the algorithm to notify the user of this right away.

Comment: To do this directly, you'll need to test various criteria for determining a draw; what have you determined so far?  Alternately, you can play out all possible continuations to see whether there's *any* path to a win.  You seem to have a start on the first; please elaborate on your current state of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check all possible runs of 4-in-a-row on the board, horizontal, vertical and diagonal. If all of them contain at least one A and at least one B then it's going to be a tie. If there is even one that is made up of a combination of empty and A or empty and B (assuming there are no rows of 4-in-a-row A or 4-in-a-row B, in which case you already have a win), then a win by A or B is still possible.

You probably already have code to check for a win, so just adapt it to check for 4-in-a-row of A or empty, or 4-in-a-row of B or empty instead of 4-in-a-row of A, or 4-in-a-row of B. If it fails to detect a possible win then a tie is inevitable.

One wrinkle is when there are a small number of empty spaces on the board. In this case you need to work out how many remaining moves A and B have and only allow them that many number of empties in the calculation, e.g. check for 4-in-a-row of A and a maximum of 2 empties. For example if there are 5 empty spaces left and it's B's turn then A has 2 moves left and B has 3.

One case it won't handle is if there is a single empty column left - there might be enough space for one player to stack 4 in a row but they can't because the players have to alternate.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Let me work out the implementation details with my existing code and when it works, I will mark this answer as accepted. Regards.

Comment: This algorithm was successfully implemented and unit tested for the horizontal case. I will do the other cases later on and report any findings (if any), but I consider this question answered.